# Multiple overrideGuard configurations resulting into tests failures

Tags: javascript, jestjs, authorization, nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I have a nestjs application and some nestjs tests written in jest and they make use of guards. So in the tests i have created fake guards and trying to override them.

Due to multiple overrideGuard configurations I am seeing test failures and my test failures are like

```
 ● Organization › POST /organizations

    expected 201 "Created", got 500 "Internal Server Error"

      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertStatus (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:268:12)
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test._assertFunction (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:283:11)
      at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Test.assert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:173:18)
      at Server.localAssert (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
```

Other error is and i think the main reason for above error would be as well

```
[Nest] 94156  - 09/21/2022, 11:06:43 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid role(s): []
AccessControlError: Invalid role(s): []
```

Guards are bound to endpoint in this way, attaching some part of the code

```
import * as common from "@nestjs/common";
import * as swagger from "@nestjs/swagger";
import * as nestAccessControl from "nest-access-control";
import * as defaultAuthGuard from "../../auth/defaultAuth.guard";

@common.UseGuards(defaultAuthGuard.DefaultAuthGuard, nestAccessControl.ACGuard)
export class OrganizationControllerBase {
  constructor(
    protected readonly service: OrganizationService,
    protected readonly rolesBuilder: nestAccessControl.RolesBuilder
  ) {}

  @common.UseInterceptors(AclValidateRequestInterceptor)
  @nestAccessControl.UseRoles({
    resource: "Organization",
    action: "create",
    possession: "any",
  })
  @common.Post()
  @swagger.ApiCreatedResponse({ type: Organization })
  @swagger.ApiForbiddenResponse({ type: errors.ForbiddenException })
  async create(
    @common.Body() data: OrganizationCreateInput
  ): Promise<Organization> {
    return await this.service.create({
      data: data,
      select: {
        id: true,
        createdAt: true,
        updatedAt: true,
        name: true,
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Some parts of spec code(tests) looks like below

```
const basicAuthGuard = {
  canActivate: (context: ExecutionContext) => {
    const argumentHost = context.switchToHttp();
    const request = argumentHost.getRequest();
    request.user = {
      roles: ["user"],
    };
    return true;
  },
};

const acGuard = {
  canActivate: () => {
    return true;
  },
};
```

```
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: OrganizationService,
          useValue: service,
        },
      ],
      controllers: [OrganizationController],
      imports: [MorganModule.forRoot(), ACLModule],
    })
      .overrideGuard(DefaultAuthGuard)
      .useValue(basicAuthGuard)
      .overrideGuard(ACGuard)
      .useValue(acGuard)
      .compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });
```

When I removed the `.overrideGuard(ACGuard).useValue(acGuard)` then test passed fine but I am not sure why is that happening ?

Why the later overrideGuard setting cancelling the previous overrideGuard configuration ?

**Edit 1 :**

Project on github : https://github.com/shubhwip/sample-app

Steps to reproduce :

- Clone the repository https://github.com/shubhwip/sample-app
- Make sure to have node version installed > 14
- Run `npm install`
- Run `npm run test`
- Issue should be reproduced

Comment: Do you happen to have something that reproduces this behavior? Code that can be ran locally? I've not heard of this before

Comment: it is on github `https://github.com/shubhwip/sample-app`. clone then run `npm install` and then `npm run test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guard mocks are actually working fine, and you can verify this by adding in a `console.log()` to your mocks. The issue is coming from your `AclFilterResponseInterceptor` and `AclValidateRequestInterceptor` interceptors, where you pass `role: permissionRoles.role`. That value is `undefined`, so when going into the `accesscontrol` library, it is invalid and the error is thrown subsequently.

I was able to fix this in your local code by using `role: context.switchToHttp().getRequest().user.roles`.

I believe this fails when mocking the AC guard because the [`AcGuard` actually mutates the `roles` metadata](https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-access-control/blob/master/src/access-control.guard.ts#L42). By modifying a reference to the `roles`, the metadata pulled later in the interceptor is the mutated metadata, not the directly set metadata. One of JavaScript's [pass-by-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) quirks with objects.

Comment: Thank you very much Jay. I really appreciate it. I wanted to know since in my mocked `AcGuard` I am returning true directly so i am not mutating any roles data so how that is later affected in interceptors. Yes by adding `role: context.switchToThttp().getRequest().user.roles` it works and if the state is mutated then how should we handle this ? in `nest-access-control` layer or in the `sample app` itself ?

Comment: To me, it looks like you're doing e2e testing, so my preference is that as little is mocked as possible. The fact that the metadata gets mutated makes it hard to say what the actual mock guard functionality should be